# How to compare an array from a json object with a normal array?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to do something like this

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE json_array_elements(t.data->'other_field'->my_array) && ARRAY['some_values']
```

But I can't, due to this error
`ERROR:  set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE`
I searched a lot for a solution without using other joins or stuff like that.
So how can I do something like this in query as less complex as it can be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the array elements are strings, you can use the `?|` [operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html). But that only works with `jsonb` values. As your column seems to be a `json` you need to cast it:

```
select *
from the_table t
where (t.data::jsonb -> 'other_field' -> 'my_array') ?| array['..', '..'];
```